# JS Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript

I have problem here ...

```
if (currentScreen=="object" && currentItem[1]!=null){
  gotoElement(currentItem[0], currentItem[1], true, false, currentScreen);
}  else  {
    loadContent("objectMain.php?objectClass=" + currentItem[0],"centerDiv");
} else {
    target=getTargetFromCurrentScreen(currentScreen);
    loadContent(target,"centerDiv"); 
}

enableWidget('menuBarRedoButton');
if (historyPosition == 0) {
    disableWidget('menuBarUndoButton');
}
```

Error is :

> "unexpected token else".

Someone can help me ?

Comment: you can't have two else's

Answer (score 1):

You've to use `else if()` instead of two successif `else`'s :

```
if (first_condition){

} else if(second_condition) {

} else {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
if (someCondition) {

} else {

} else {

}
```

Which logically makes no sense.  `else` means "in all other cases".  So what would a *second* `else` possibly mean?

You probably meant to have a *second* `if` condition:

```
if (someCondition) {

} else if (anotherCondition) {

} else {

}
```